# What is the best practice for IMAP connection?

Tags: imap

I think that the concept of `connection` is not fully clear to me.

I am building a small read-only webmail for a project, and I am using the `net/imap` library of ruby.

Should I open a connection, authenticate, do the action and disconnect each time?

Or should I open a connection and passing around for my application?
Can someone clear to me the concept of IMAP connection?

I have see that a lot of client open multiple connection at the same time, why?

Comment: you're fishing for opinions, which are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: opinions? I am trying to understand the concept of `imap connection` that it is not clear to me. Are questions about best practices illegal now?

Comment: Multithread clients can use multiple connections to avoid locks. Perhaps these clients implement IMAP-connection-pool, like SQL-connection-pool in **ADO.NET**.

Answer (score 1):

An IMAP connection is expensive enough that if you'll want to keep it if you're going to use it again in the next seconds (perhaps even minutes). It contains much more state and is much more expensive to set up than the HTTP connections with which you're probably familiar.

However, IMAP connections die randonly. So many NAT middleboxes are surprised when a TCP connection remains quiet for three minutes, as IMAP connections often do. So you'll probably want to accept that the connections can die, and reopen if necessary.

Comment: But if I open a connection, and have 10 users on my webmail. The first make a search that takes some time, if the other action use the same connection have to wait until the search has finished before being processed?

Comment: Technically no, but fully asynchronous IMAP client libraries are rare, and it's somewhat unclear if any servers actually support processing multiple commands simultaenously, but it is allowed by specification for it to do so.

Comment: You cannot use one IMAP connection for two users. Part of the state it keeps is the user's login.